# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) in react project

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react project I get the following error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports
Check the render method of App

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { apiUrl, filterData } from "./data";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Cards from './components/Cards';
import Filter from './components/Filter'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
  
      <Navbar/>
      <Filter 
        filterData = {filterData}
      />
     <Cards/>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here is Navbar

```
import React from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <h1>Top Courses</h1>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Here is the Filter components

```
import React from 'react'

const Filter = ({filterData}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {filterData.map((data) => {
        return (<button>
            {data.title};
        </button>)
      })}
   </div>
  )
}

export default Filter
```

Comment: You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Comment: Please show the files exporting the Navbar, Cards and Filter components

Comment: I have shared the code above of all components and in Cards components i have not written the code yet.

Comment: Issue has been solved

Answer (score 0):

You might have received this because your Cards component is empty. Try making it a proper functional component with any JSX code (even a simple `h1` or `div`) and exporting it